# Counting A User's Temporary Suspensions

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

Is there a way to tell how many times a user has been [temporarily suspended](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/), and is there a limit to how many times someone can be temporarily suspended?

Comment: That isn't public info for users. Only moderators and staff would have the ability to see how many times a user has been suspended.

Comment: just like on any question on meta, either because people feel you haven't researched it, or because they feel the implied question (which is "should we see it") should be answered no. Don't overstress downvotes on meta...

Comment: Maybe people don't like the idea of a non-moderator wanting to examine another user like that? Still seems like a valid question to me even if I'm not interested in doing it.

Comment: @Patrice no stress, but I don't know where I could research this, hence the question. None of the other suspension questions I found touched on this.

Comment: Oh that's fair. I think that it's not put anywhere in a question, I think it's more the general vibe given by Mods around suspensions and the fact that they just aren't discussed. So some meta regulars might have that answer come instinctively, without realizing it's virtually impossible to find?

Comment: I asked this question because I saw a user I recognized with a high rep count showing their current rep as 1, and when I looked at their account I saw the temporary suspension notice. I know that this user has been suspended multiple times throughout the years, and wondered why they're allowed to keep their account after repeated suspensions. and if there was a rule about the number of suspensions a user can receive.

Answer (score 8):

You need to be elected as a moderator on the site to see the past history of a user's suspensions.

There's no hard limit on number of suspensions, although at some point the moderation team may determine that you're no longer welcome entirely.  Such situations are typically evaluated on a case by case basis though.

Comment: I heard somewhere that the suggested suspension length takes past suspensions into account.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yes.  But note that's the *suggested* length.  It's just a baseline, to which you can move up or down based on specifics.

Comment: But this also plays into the 20 year suspensions right?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Pretty sure those are all cases that deviate from the baseline due to a determination that the user was a special case.  I don't think there is any standard for when you go to a 20 year suspension.

Comment: @ryanyuyu - Moderators can only issue suspensions of up to a year in length. The system suggests an escalation of 7 days -> 30 days -> 365 days for subsequent suspensions, but we override that much of the time. Only staff members can issue suspensions longer than a year, or network-wide ones. Those tend to come in more extreme cases.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a way to tell how many times a user has been temporarily suspended(?)

Not unless you're an elected moderator or employee, and in all reality, it shouldn't matter.  Suspensions aren't meant to remain as a stigma held against you for the rest of one's continued participation; they're genuinely meant for one to be put [in time-out](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/), and once that time is served, then the transgression is forgiven and we can all move past it.

> [I]s there a limit to how many times someone can be temporarily suspended?

In *practice*, yes; suspensions escalate depending on the severity of the offense.  You can be suspended anywhere from 24 hours to *eternity*, but the system itself will naturally double one's time spent away from the site depending on how recently they've been suspended when they re-offend.

I *want* to say that there's no limit in theory, but c'mon, after the first 20 times you've been suspended from the site, then perhaps a longer vacation is required...