# What is the penalty for hate speech?

Tags: discussion, moderation, account-suspension

I don't come across hate speech often on Stack Overflow, but today I came across a suggested edit that changed a string in the code from "Do you know?" to "Do you know that Ukraine is a neo-nazi rogue state?" and a link to the Wikipedia article for the country of Ukraine to the article for Neo-Nazism. To add insult to injury, the edit summary was "Added some facts about Ukraine". I'm not an expert in classifying hate speech or moderation, but I'd say it's pretty fair to call this hate speech.

I rejected it as spam and raised a flag about it and the user got suspended for 7 days. For actions so blatantly against the "be kind" policy, I thought that a longer suspension (at least 30 days) would be warranted, if not destruction, even on a first offense.

Am I wrong here, and if so what should the penalty be? Also, are there standard penalties/suspension lengths for this kind of conduct, or is it just what the mod feels is fair? If so, what are they?

Comment: 7 days is the suggested suspension period by the system from what I understand. See [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371968/counting-a-users-temporary-suspensions#comment617116_371969) by a moderator: "_The system suggests an escalation of 7 days -> 30 days -> 365 days for subsequent suspensions_"

Comment: "*if not deletion*" deletion without suspension is usually meaningless since the user can just recreate the account and repeat the offense. On the other hand, destroying the user will automatically apply a 365-day (not 7-day anymore) suspension without any helpful message.

Comment: @AndrewT. I think destruction is what I was looking for, rather than deletion. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @AndrewT. That's not entirely accurate. The system only applies an automatic 365-day suspension if the profile is destroyed for "This user was created to post spam or nonsense and has no other positive participation" or deleted for "This user is no longer welcome to participate on the site" and no other delete or destroy reasons.

Comment: @chivracq: We *were* wondering. What context is it used in? Or is it a [SIA](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=SIA)? No [reasonable effort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPR) [comes up with it](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/SPR#Noun). The closest is [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Sex,_religion_and_politics) (though it does have some Wikipedia jargon on it).

Comment: I don't think we should be conflating usernames claiming stances with actual vandalism on posts.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It depends, and it's generally a matter of moderator discretion.

*In general*, we follow a standard escalation:

- Warning (skipped for more problematic behavior, or can sometimes be 1-3 days)
- 7-day suspension
- 30-day suspension
- 365-day suspension

In this case (I handled the flag, although I'd already issued the suspension by the time I got to it), I elected to skip a warning and go straight to a 7-day suspension, given, as you note, the severity of the conduct.  In selecting that, I took into account that the user had *otherwise* been contributing positively, and that they hadn't done this in other cases.  Had they created an account *solely* to post that, I probably would have imposed a harsher penalty, as it would appear that they were unlikely to contribute positively.

Our goal in moderating is generally to reform and deter future bad behavior, rather than to punish.  Our standard message for "Abusive to others" includes reminders to think about the impact of one's interactions on others, for instance.  The suspension is "to cool down"—we're giving them a week to think about if that's *really* how they should be behaving.  And if they come back and do it again...well, then the suspension is likely to be much longer.  But hopefully we'll have made ourselves clear, they won't do it again, and they'll go on to contribute positively going forward.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go about doing it. Ideally users are guided towards redemption. Overly punishing, for example as the OP suggested with a deletion, can also have unintended negative side effects such as sock accounts or retaliation from the user, and also can create an imbalance in other similar situations if leniency were used.